# Add conditional custom option to 'Display name publicly as' dropdown

Tags: custom-field, user-roles

Besides the built-in "Display name publicly as" options, I would like to add a custom "***name + nickname + surname***" option to the dropdown.

This custom option should be determined by two conditions:

1. ***Name + nickname + surname*** should automatically be used for the editor role.
2. ***Nickname*** should automatically be used for all other roles.

** The field to change this should also be hidden for all roles except for administrators.*

I will be extremely grateful for help.

Comment: There's no filter to do that https://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/wp-admin/user-edit.php. However, this could be manually done using the https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user action.

Answer (score 1):

While you can't edit the dropdown list, you can achieve what you want as long as you are able to edit your theme or if your theme uses the standard `the_author()` template tag.

To recast your question, you want:

1. Editor's names to show as Name + nickname + surname
2. Other names to show as nickname
3. No-one to be able to change this except Admins

I'm assuming at the moment that point 3 is just to prevent people changing things and that not even admins really need to change 1 & 2.

## Theme Edit Solution

Anywhere in your theme that you display the author's name, why not use your own code:

```
if ( user_can( get_the_author_meta('ID'), 'editor' ) ) {
    echo get_the_author_meta('first_name');
    echo ' ';
    echo get_the_author_meta('nickname');
    echo ' ';
    echo get_the_author_meta('last_name');
} else {
    echo get_the_author_meta('nickname');
}

/* Use a clever way of joining the parts of the name together
   if you wish, the style here is just for clarity.
*/
```

**NB** - `get_the_author_meta` pulls the requested field from the global `$authordata`, so you could simplify the code by accessing the global directly, although it's better practice to use the abstraction that `get_the_author_meta` gives you.

## Plugin Solution

If you don't want to edit your theme and if your theme uses the standard `the_author()` template tag then make yourself a small plugin that hooks into the filter `the_author`.

```
function wpse_213437_author_display_name( $display_name ) {
    if ( user_can( get_the_author_meta('ID'), 'editor' ) ) {
        $display_name = get_the_author_meta('first_name');
        $display_name .=  ' ';
        $display_name .= get_the_author_meta('nickname');
        $display_name .= ' ';
        $display_name .= get_the_author_meta('last_name');
    } else {
        $display_name = get_the_author_meta('nickname');
    }
    return $display_name;
}

add_filter( 'the_author', 'wpse_213437_author_display_name' );
```

## Allowing Admin override

As an exercise for the reader, you can add your own fields to the user edit screen.  So while you can't augment the built-in display name dropdown, you could build your own or add a text input for an override value and then hook into `the_author` as above to use your new value.